# Ocaml: function with no parameters to return generic pair in tuple list

Tags: ocaml

I wanted to write a function with following signature to use in association dictionary

```
    empty: unit -> ('a * 'b) list
```

I am assuming it will be something like

```
    let empty () = ...
```

But how can I create a list with specific type?

Comment: why make it a function at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function returns an empty list it will have the type you want:

```
# let empty () : ('a * 'b) list = [];;
val empty : unit -> ('a * 'b) list = <fun>
```

The natural type of this function is `unit -> 'a list`, but OCaml will let you "slim down" the type into a more specific one.

You can specify a type for any expression in the form `(` *expr* `:` *type* `)`:

```
# let empty () = ([] : ('a * 'b) list);;
val empty : unit -> ('a * 'b) list = <fun>
```

Of course, the type has to be correct (must unify with the inferred type of the expression).

**Update**

As newacct points out, you could use a value rather than a function.

```
# let (empty : ('a * 'b) list) = [];;
val empty : ('a * 'b) list = []
```

This is a common way to define an empty pure structure (as in the Map module).